# ionic sidemenu show's blank screen while swiping the screen

Tags: css, sass, ionic-framework

I create my project in ionic sidemenu, My project structure is like this

1) I select the menu item from items

2) It open the screen and there is list for items

3) Again I select the one item from that above items

4) It shows list of items

Now problem is that when my finger on profile pictures left corner and I am going to swipe it, from left to right it show problem, It shows blank screen first. And when that blank screen come to main page, That menu item not working properly. Also this problem only founds on iOS not in Android.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem as you. The blank gap is due to the new "Swipe To Go Back" feature in ionic (see http://blog.ionic.io/rc0-swipe-to-go-back/). In fact, the view shown between your side-menu and your current view is not void, but the last view in your history.

Use this to **disable** the Swipe To Go Back feature in your application:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
```

You can put this code in a config page like that :

```
var app = angular.module('config', ['ionic']);

app.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
      $ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
});
```

$ionicConfigProvider documentation: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/

Also, if you want to disable this **on one specific view only** (see directive ionView doc on ionic website, I unfortunately can't post more than 2 links since I have less than 10 rep):

```
<ion-view can-swipe-back="false">
    ...
<ion-view>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This issue will arise when I set cache:"true" in app.js - .config function. When I remove it from .config function it works properly. But If you want to use disable the cache in that case you go ahead the with another answer or remove the cache.